# how to access all user dashboard on fronted page

Tags: plugins, css, admin, mysql, html

i am new for WordPress and i am creating a membership web site. i have my requirement access user dashboard on fronted page like same to same backed user dashboard. with all activity like change user role editor to subscriber from fronted side

please help me

Comment: That's a huge amount of work, you're going to have to narrow it down

Comment: suppose i am administrator and i want to change other user role so how to change role other member that my requirement but not change backed only change from fronted side ....

Comment: please help me how to change other user role from frontend because my site is membership site.